# Uniform continuity of $f(x)=x^2+x$

Tags: real-analysis

How do we justify the uniformly continuity of $f(x)=x^2+x$ on $(0,\infty)$?

I really need someone's help to solve this for my exam revision.

Comment: We don't? $x^2 + x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: $|x^2 - y^2| = |x+y||x-y| > C|x-y|$ for any C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $x,y>0$ with $|x-y|\leq\delta $ it holds $$\epsilon=1>|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^2+x-y^2-y|.$$ This is in particular true if $x=y+\delta$, so we get
$$1>|(x+\delta)^2+(x+\delta)-x^2-x|=\delta^2+\delta+2\delta x>2\delta x.$$
Taking $x = 1/\delta$, we obtain the contradiction $1>2$ and so $f$ can not be uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Note however that $f$ is uniformly continuous on every *bounded* subinterval $I$ of $(0,\infty)$. For example, take $I=(0,10^{89}]$, then $f$ in uniformly continuous on $I$ because it is continuous on $[0,10^{89}]$.

Comment: thanks bro! everything solved!

Comment: Hi sir! Just wondering if we got the interval on (0, 1), does the uniform continuity exists?

Comment: @JonSirNo the function $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ because it is continuous on $[0,1]$. To prove that, you can use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$$f: x\mapsto x^2+x$$ is not uniformly continuous at $(0,+\infty) $ because

if we take
$$u_n=\sqrt {n+1} $$
and
$$v_n=\sqrt {n} $$
then we have
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(u_n-v_n)=0$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(f (u_n)-f (v_n))=1\ne 0$$

Comment: why do we use the "u and v" approach?

Comment: With this approach it is very easy to see that $ f $ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,∞) $.

Comment: okay thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Your function $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$ !!